# Tests for race condition in Elixir

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to write a tests for a case when I need to test a method with `from(...) |> lock("FOR UPDATE")` and get sure that row will be blocked from other processes. I've tried to write this test:

```
defmodule Chain.BalanceTest do
  use Chain.DataCase

  describe "concurrent" do
    setup do
      {:ok, %Chain.Address{id: id}} = Chain.Address.create_address(%{user_id: 1, nonce: 0})

      :ok
    end

    test "test locking" do
      parent = self()
      %Chain.Address{id: id} = from(a in Chain.Address) |> Repo.one()

      {:ok, new_pid} =
        Task.start_link(fn ->
          assert_receive :wait, 5000

          Repo.transaction(fn ->
            address = Chain.Address.lock_address(id)
            Apex.ap("1 - #{address.nonce}")
            Chain.Address.update_nonce(address)
          end)

          send(parent, :done)
        end)

      Repo.transaction(fn ->
        address = Chain.Address.lock_address(id)
        Apex.ap("2 - #{address.nonce}")
        send(new_pid, :wait)
        Chain.Address.update_nonce(address)
      end)

      assert_receive :done, 5000

      fetched = Chain.Address.get!(id)
      assert fetched.nonce == 2
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that it works in a transaction isolation level and **always** works even if I remove `lock` from `Chain.Addres.lock_address`. I've tried to `Sandbox.checkout` in a `Task` but in that case `Task` process doesn't see that address because parent process didn't commit it.

So is there any way to trigger race condition during test and\or persist data in idiomatic way so another process can read it and it won't ruin all other tests?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to detect deadlocks in general case. You can use TLA+ to model your application and check that model for errors.

Alternatively you can check out [Concuerror](https://concuerror.com) to try to generate deadlocks in test suite, however this will not guarantee you that there are no deadlocks in your model.